# Emacs server init when called without file

Tags: hooks, emacs-daemon

Whenever I use `emacsclient`, I tend to use it without a file argument. This is because my emacs file finder is generally better than my shell file finder.

Unfortunately, when `emacsclient` is not given a file argument, neither `server-visit-hook` nor `server-switch-hook` are fired, and I'm left without crucial bits of server setup.

How can I work around this limitation?

EDIT: Added example code.

```el
(let ((my/evil-mode-line-face-cookies nil))
  (defun my/evil-set-mode-line-face (&rest args)
    (cl-destructuring-bind (bg-color fg-color)
        (pcase evil-state
          (`normal  '("white" "blue"))
          (`emacs   '("white" "green"))
          (`insert  '("black" "grey"))
          (`visual  '("white" "cyan"))
          (`replace '("white" "red"))
          (other    '("grey"  "black")))
      (mapc #'face-remap-remove-relative my/evil-mode-line-face-cookies)
      (setq my/evil-mode-line-face-cookies
            (list (face-remap-add-relative
                   'mode-line
                   mode-line
                   `((:foreground ,fg-color :background ,bg-color)
                     mode-line))

                  (face-remap-add-relative
                   'mode-line-buffer-id
                   mode-line-buffer-id
                   `((:foreground ,fg-color)
                     mode-line-buffer-id)))))))

(add-hook 'post-command-hook #'my/evil-set-mode-line-face)
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions #'my/evil-set-mode-line-face)
```

Comment: What do you do in those hooks?  If you are using `dired` as your file finder, then you could simply pass the directory as your argument.

Comment: @suvayu I do things like initialize clipboard handlers and `xterm-mouse-mode`, which are specific to the current frame. I also set some faces depending on the current display's color capabilities.

Comment: You could move those to `before-make-frame-hook` or `after-make-frame-functions`.  Then you would have the advantage of your customisations working also in a normal session.

Comment: @suvayu those hooks aren't run for terminal sessions.

Comment: PythonNut: Sure they are. You just need to *both* run the function directly in your init file, and *also* add it to the hook, as unless you start emacs as a daemon, the initial frame is created *before* your init file runs.

Comment: @phils I do run it as a daemon, actually.

Comment: Presumably at some point you'll run a non-daemon Emacs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`after-make-frame-functions` is what I use in these situations.

Here's an example, adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5066313/324105

```el
(defun my-frame-behaviours (&optional frame)
  "Make frame- and/or terminal-local changes."
  (with-selected-frame (or frame (selected-frame))
    ;; do things...
    ))
;; Evaluate immediately (for non-daemon emacs), and also
;; upon frame creation (for new terminals via emacsclient).
(my-frame-behaviours)
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'my-frame-behaviours)
```

Comment: This is not working for the specific case of adding relative face remaps based on the current `evil-state`. I have no idea why.

Comment: Add an example to the question?

Comment: I've added it (with some simplifications).

Comment: Oh well it's obviously because I'm not including your `(with-selected-frame ...)` bits. Sorry about that.

Comment: That may have been due to my starting with example code which was all about terminal-local changes, and which consequently didn't include that wrapper (because the frame wasn't actually important on that occasion). Glad to hear it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Another, possibly more hacky, solution:

```el
(defun my/server-init (&rest args)
  (message "Initializing the server!"))
(advice-add 'server-execute :after #'my/server-init)
```