# Emacs daemon not working properly, Emacs server runs fine

Tags: daemon, server, emacs-daemon

**Version**

GNU Emacs 25.1.50.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9) of 2016-04-25

Xubuntu 16.04, Linux kernel 4.4

In my `.emacs` I have the following settings

```
(require 'server)
(unless (server-running-p)
(server-start))
```

When I call `emacsclient -c -a emacs`, it works like a charm. When there is no Emacs instance running in background or in another workspace, Emacs will be called. Otherwise, emacsclient will be called.

But I want to have Emacs running in the background. For that, I use the Emacs daemon.

When calling `emacs --daemon`, I see my `dot-emacs` being loaded in the terminal. After that, I call `emacsclient -c` or `emacsclient`, but it cannot detect the Emacs daemon/server.

When Googling around, I found this answer: http://www.tychoish.com/posts/getting-emacs-daemon-to-work-right/

So I added it to my commands that it will be called on startup:

```
emacs -u renefroger(my username) --daemon --eval "(setq default-frame-alist \ '((font-backend . \"xft\") (font . \"[FONT]-[SIZE]\")))" -l ~/.emacs
```

After a restart, I call `emacsclient -nw` but it makes it somewhat unusable. I got sometimes the message  `Error reading from stdin` when I do sometihing like <kbd>M-x Helm</kbd>, and the colors are not right, while they're fine the console Emacs with the Emacs server instead of daemon. So I'm puzzled what's going on with the Emacs daemon.

How could I get Emacs daemon working properly?

Comment: Have you looked at this http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5454/7045

Comment: Yes, I tried it. But after starting Emacs daemon, the emacsclient also keeps starting the Emacs dameon.

Comment: Sorry I'm not able to understand your case exactly or how it differs from others with similar issues. I even tried editing your question.

Comment: ReneFroger: I don't really follow the question, but differences between daemon and not-daemon servers are sometimes on account of setting frame- or terminal-local values in your init file *before* any frame exists. http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/16485 should help if you establish that you are indeed doing this.

Comment: I beleive its a bug. I did the test with a clean config in 24.5.1 and I didn't have any issues.

Comment: @Joafigue, you're right. It was with my configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After bisecting my Emacs configuration, I found the culprit.

Remove the `(setq server-socket-dir "your-path")` from your configuration.